# Hartshorne Example II.7.8.6

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-geometry

I have a question about Example II.7.8.6 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry.

Let $k$ algebraically closed field,
$V=(t^4,t^3u,tu^3,u^4)$ and $V'=(t^4,t^3u+at^2u^2,tu^3,u^4)(a\in k^*)$ are two quartic curves in $\mathbb{P}^3_k$.
How can I show these are not equivalent by an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^3_k$.

In Joe Harris's Algebraic Geometry, he defines ration quartic curves as curves defined by  the parameterization
$[X_0^4-\beta X_0^3X_1,X_0^3X_1-\beta X_0^2X_2^2,\alpha X_0^2X_1^2-X_0X_1^3,\alpha X_0X_1^3-X_1^4]$.
So it is slightly different from one in Hartshorne's book and it doesn't help.

Also Maccaulay2 showed the homogeneous ideal of $V'$ is
$(z^4-xw^3,4y^3z^2-y^4w+4xyz^2w-6xy^2w^2-x^2w^3+x^2s^2,y^5+20xy^2z^2-10xy^3w+4x^2z^2w-15x^2yw^2-4x^2z^2-x^2yw)$
It is so complicated so that it doesn't help.

Comment: naive try: we know that all automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^3_k$, which is $GL(4,k)/k^{\times}$.

Comment: If $[a_{ij}] \in GL(4.k)$ give such a automorphism, I can see that the point
($a_{12}t^4+a_{12}t^3u+a_{13}tu^3+a_{14}u^4$,
$a_{21}t^4+a_{22}t^3u+a_{23}tu^3+a_{24}u^4$,
$a_{31}t^4+a_{32}t^3u+a_{33}tu^3+a_{34}u^4$,
$a_{41}t^4+a_{42}t^3u+a_{43}tu^3+a_{44}u^4$)
is in V'.  
Is it true that  
$a_{21}t^4+a_{22}t^3u+a_{23}tu^3+a_{24}u^4=t^3u+at^2u^2$?
If so, I can use linearly independence.

Answer (score 0):

The homogeneous ideal of $V$ contains a quadratic polynomium whereas the homogeneous ideal of $V'$ does not. This property whould be preserved by an automorphism of $\Bbb{P}^3$ since an automorphism is given by linear forms.

*Edit*: This argument is flawed. As KReiser pointed out in the comments, the homogeneous ideal of any quartic rational curve in $\Bbb{P}^3$ will always contain a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: How do you know the homogeneous ideal of $V'$ has to quadratic polynomial?  If it's based on the Macaulay2 result: that would require that the calculation is done using something like a deglex monomial order, where you also need to make sure the degree of $s$ is considered to be 0.  (Or, the calculation is made over $\mathbb{Q}(s)[x,y,z,w]$ as opposed to $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z,w,s]$.)

Comment: Also this isn't true, the evaluation map on global sections $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^3}(2)\to\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1}(8)$ is a map from a 10-dimensional vector space to a 9-dimensional vector space, so it always has a nontrivial kernel. (I like the way this is going, though, maybe there's a way to salvage it?)